# Regex to retrieve specific text

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a lot of pages with text and I have to retrieve specific values. It doesn't have to be 100% accurate but I don't want too many invalid values either. The values I'm looking for can be anywhere in the blocks of text. I will match the extracted values to a baseline containing all the valid values to clean the data but my current regex is either extracting all the words or nothing I can use.

I'm currently splitting the text into words and match it to the regex but this retrieves almost every word. Also the min number of characters is 2 and the max is 37. I'm using this in javascript for Brio Hyperion.

```
/^\S[A-Z0-9A-Z]{2,37}\S*$/
```

What regex should I use to retrieve this values ?

```
AEDDBO0023
AED02GS2330
AEBDG0233
GSOOG2345
INCG00522133
AESBOFGL2321
GSCO231145
```

Example text :

> > Random text not important:Random text not important,Random text not
> >     important::Random text not important'Random text not important Random
> >     text not important Random text not importantRandom text not
> >     importantRandom text not important Random text not important
> >     Warehousename:**AEDDBO0023** Random text not importantRandom text not
> >     important
> >     **AED02GS2330** Random text not importantRandom text not importantRandom text not important "A Random text not important"Random
> >     text not importantRandom text not importantRandom text not
> >     importantRandom text not important Random text not importantRandom
> >     text not importantThe following items : 
> >     **AEBDG0233 GSOOG2345 INCG00522133 AESBOFGL2321**
> >         Random text not importantRandom text not **GSCO231145** importantRandom text not importantRandom text not importantRandom text
> >     not importantRandom text not importantRandom text not importantRandom
> >     text not importantRandom text not importantRandom text not
> >     importantRandom text not important

Added from OP's comment:

```
{ 
var textBlock = ActiveDocument.Sections["Results"].Columns["Detailed Decription"].GetCell(j); // Split found host names in rows 
try { 
    linesArray = IncDescription.toUpperCase().split ('\n'); 
} catch (e) {
    Application.Alert(e.toString()); 
} 
for (i = 0; i< linesArray.length; i++) { // match found strings to the hosts regular expression 
    splitArray = linesArray [i].split(' '); 
    for (k=0; k <splitArray.length; k++) { 
        if ( splitArray [k].match (/[a-zA-Z]{2,37}*[0-9]{1,}/g) !== null) {
            try {}
```

Comment: That regex really doesn't makes too much sense to me... Cannot you narrow the format of the important words? For example, can there be letters after the numbers or is it always numbers at the beginning + letters at end?

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning, it should always start with letters and end with numbers. I'm just trying to learn how to use regex, it makes sense it doesn't make sense :D

Comment: Please detail more... how much letters/numbers max? Any maximum/minimum length for the words?

Comment: it can be between 2 and 37 characters long but the words with less than 6 are usually exceptions so it's worth matching only strings between 6 and 37 characters long. Also the standard format is that it start with minimum 4 letters and ends with ~6 numbers but this changes depending on the length of the string. thanks for the help.

Comment: You should explain yourself better... And try to find some more robust pattern if you want us to help. Since I've lost too much time doing something that doesn't fit what you need, I'm off. Good luck with it.

Comment: Unfortunately the words values I'm looking for have a very general format, that's why I'm matching it after to a baseline containing all of them. I just don't want to get millions of invalid values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about a simple

```
\b[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*[0-9]\b
```

See it [here online on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2v40s)

`\b` is a word boundary

Just start with a uppercase letter, then any amount of uppercase letters and digits and as last character a digit.

Comment: This works for most words but for some reason retrieves also words containing punctuation and white spaces.

Comment: Words start always with 4 letters.

Comment: @m0skit0 read his question and comments again, The minimum length is 2 characters. The 4 letters at the start are the standard, but there can also be shorter ones.

Comment: @CiprianGrigore this regex will neither match punctuation nor will it match whitespace if you are using it like this `/\b[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*[0-9]\b/g`

Comment: Maybe you should read again. Quoting Ciprian: "Also the standard format is that it start with minimum 4 letters"

Comment: /\b[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*[0-9]\b/g is working ! Is there a way to exclude words that include brackets () ? Thanks

Comment: @m0skit0 I have read this with 4 is standard and I quoted that also in my comment. Qoting Ciprian: "Also the min number of characters is 2 ..." (I ignore the maximum).

Comment: Your quote is incomplete: "but the words with less than 6 are usually exceptions so it's worth matching only strings between 6 and 37 characters long"

Comment: @CiprianGrigore what do you mean by "exclude words that include brackets ()" my regex will not match any brackets. (Ofcourse it will match sucha word included in bracket like this `(ABCD1234)`)

Comment: Most words start with 4 letters but there are a lot of exceptions. We can exclude the words with less than 6 characters like AE23 OR E2 but words like AED134 or AB4133 are desirable. stema's solution is working for most of them but retrieves some words that contain brackets.

Comment: This is one of the words retrieved : NATERAJGSGA(ASG0032). Can I extract the (ASG0032) only ? If not, I'd rather exclude the whole word than to retrieve it in this format.

Comment: @m0skit0 I quoted from the question not from the comment. The OP wanted it to make it easier, by narrowing down the specification. Why should I not go for the general solution? And your statement is clearly wrong "Words start always with 4 letters", they do not.

Comment: Comments are there for a reason: for you to read them. And of course he wants it narrower (not easier) because otherwise he would get all words on the text... And sorry but that's not my statement but OP's. Anyway I'm not discussing this anymore.

Comment: @CiprianGrigore [See your word here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2v41h) Here it behaves as you expected, I don't know what happens in your code. The first part "NATERAJGSGA" can't be matched, because it didn't end with a digit, the brackets can also not be matched so it will only return with "ASG0032"

Comment: It must be a difference in the regex engine. Anyway it works well enough for my needs so I will use this one. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like:

```
/\b[A-Z]{4}[A-Z0-9]{1,32}[0-9]\b/
```

explanation:

```
\b        : word boundary
[A-Z]{4}  : 4 letters
[         : begin character class
A-Z       : any letter from A to Z
0-9       : any digit
]         : end character class
{1,32}    : from 1 to 32 times
[0-9]     : a digit
\b        : word boundary
```

If you want to be unicode compatible:

```
/[^\pL\pN]{4}\pL[\pL\pN]{1,32}\pN[^\pL\pN]/
```

Comment: he said in comment it needs to start with a letter and end in a number so i guess /\b[A-Z][A-Z0-9]{0,35}[0-9]\b/ would be a bit more precise

Comment: /\b[A-Z0-9]{2,37}\b/
Retrieves almost every word, including punctuation sings (.,:)

Comment: @Blem: Thanks, I didn't see the comment before answering.

Comment: @CiprianGrigore: No it isn't, how do you use it ?

Comment: `{
 var textBlock = ActiveDocument.Sections["Results"].Columns["Detailed Decription"].GetCell(j);
  
  // Split found host names in rows
  try 
  {
   linesArray = IncDescription.toUpperCase().split ('\n');
  }
  catch (e)
  {
   Application.Alert(e.toString());
  }
  for (i = 0; i< linesArray.length; i++)
   {  // match found strings to the hosts regular expression
   splitArray = linesArray [i].split(' ');
   for (k=0; k <splitArray.length; k++)
    {
    if ( splitArray [k].match (/[a-zA-Z]{2,37}*[0-9]{1,}/g) !== null)
     {
     try
     {}`

Comment: Have you try with the regex I've given?

Comment: Not strict enough. Words always start with 4 letters.

Comment: for some reason it's not matching anything, I think there's an error in my code ?

Comment: @m0skit0: Is this really deserve a downvote? The requierements had change in the meantime. Then it's not so hard for the OP to correct it.

Comment: Sure. The answer is NOT correct. I will change the downvote when the answer is correct (within reasonable time). Anyway I've received way harsher downvotes...

Comment: the original poster clearly don't know what he wants, even thou he says it has minimum 4 letters at start one of the words in the example only has 3 `AED02GS2330`

Answer (score 0):

This should be a start: `/[a-zA-Z]{2,37}*[0-9]{1,}/g`

In the example text above matches

```
["AEDDBO0023", "AED02", "GS2330", "AEBDG0233", "GSOOG2345", "INCG00522133", "AESBOFGL2321", "GSCO231145"]
```

Comment: it wouldn't catch AED02GS2330

Comment: What should `{2,37}*` mean? I don't think those two quantifiers make sense together.

Answer (score -1):

Try with

```
/\b[A-Z]{4,}[0-9A-Z]*\d{4,}\b/
```

I'm assuming the letters can only be uppercase and it has at least 4 numbers at the end. Middle stuff can be any mix of letters and numbers.

Edited with I can understand from OP (which is not much...)

Comment: same problem as fuzzyalej, wont get AED02GS2330

Comment: I know, but it's not my fault when people don't know how to explain their problems...

Comment: I have added plenty of comments about what is wrong, you try to give the poster what he asks for instead of what he actually needs, and you downvote for answers that actually work for getting all the correct answers just because they don't follow what the original poster ask for even thou you agree that he dos not know what he wants

Comment: First, I don't have to guess what the OP wants. He has to tell me, the more detailed, the better answer I can come upon (if I can). And I have to give an answer to what he's asking, not to what I think he's asking or what I think it's better for him. And second, thanks for the comment!